# glPolygonMode different behavior when rendering a texture?

Tags: c++, opengl

I have a quad which I store using an EBO (it has some positional and texture coord attributes:

[image]

I can draw it using polygons like this

```
glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
```

[image]

Now if I remove that line and just switch to a shader using textures, I have a sprite being drawn.

[image]

Now if I turn on the glPolygonMode with GL_LINE again, I get this

[image]

The expected behavior: I expected to see a wireframe exactly like image #2, but I'm instead seeing something quite different. Is this normal? What could be causing this?

The only thing I did that was different was just change shaders.

Comment: The texture is transparent around its edges, so you can't see lines along the edges. `glPolygonMode` doesn't magically change the primitive type, it just changes rasterization and skips fragments.

Comment: I thought it would show me the quad wireframe again, why does it show a diagonal line

Comment: Because the texture is transparent at its edges but not transparent at its center.

Comment: ah! I didn't realize it was actually using the texture to draw! Seems obvious now thanks